# Gaussian Matrix Integral

Tags: string-theory, path-integral, matrix-model

I couldn't quite understand how we calculate the Gaussian Matrix Integral

$$\mathcal{Z}=\int dM\ e^{-N\text{tr}\left(\frac{1}{2}M^2+JM\right)},$$

where the integration measure $dM$ over the $N$ by $N$ matrix $M$ is defined as

$$dM=\prod_{i=1}^{N}dM_{ii}\prod_{i<j=1}^{N}dM_{ij}dM_{ij}^*.$$

I can see how diagonlazing the matrix $M$

$$M=U\Lambda U^\dagger,\qquad\Lambda=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_N),$$

simplifies the discussion by decoupling the action. My main problem is how the measure $dM$ transforms after this unitary transformation and how do we go on about calculating the partition function?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558062/2451

Comment: This might be physically motivated, however as it stands this is a purely mathematical problem and likely to be better received on mathematics stackexchange

Comment: You could see arxiv:2004.01171